# Not able to get the json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

```
    var myurl="https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json";

    $.ajax(
    {
     url:myurl,
     type:"POST",
     dataType:"JSONP",
     success:function(myObj)
       {
        console.log(myObj);  
       }
   });
```

I tried using the shorthand getJSON, but console throws me an error "use POST request".
And using the code above, console states that "Invalid Label".

Answer (score 1):

Use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), it is shorthand function and very efficient too.

```
var myurl="https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json";

$.getJSON(
  myurl,
  function(data) {
      //manipulate your json
});
```

But for the JSONP request, you should have callback parameter in the URL

As quoted on the documentation<sup>*[[here]](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)*</sup>

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code, try this:

```
$.post(
  myurl,
  {},
  function(data){
    alert(data);
  },'json'
);
```

the variable 'data' is a json object.

Comment: error : ""NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json""

Comment: You dont need to give empty `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain JSONP isn't AJAX at all. It doesn't use XMLHttpRequest. It's nothing more than a dynamic script element that loads JavaScript code.

Try:

```
var req = $.ajax({
    url : myurl,
    dataType : "jsonp"
});

req.success(function(myObj) {
    console.log(myObj);
});

req.error(function() {
    console.log('some error occured');
});
```

I think the end server "https://raw.github.com" does not support JSONP. So you will probably have to create a proxy endpoint on your server to access this data. Basically, create an endpoint on your own server that loads that data using whatever method makes sense (curl, etc..) and returns it exactly as-is. Then you can use regular AJAX. Hope that helps

Comment: yea..something is wrong with the api service.. anyways thnks for the help