# Ajax json respond not getting in success in POST method

Tags: jquery, jsonp, google-analytics-api

I am not getting json response/success from ajax while i am using jsonp datatype. But i am getting blank response.Is that of GAPI i am getting this issue or any other.I find similar problem 
[Not able to get the json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782361/not-able-to-get-the-json-response)

this is my jquery code

```
$.ajax({ url: 'includes/gapi.apis.php',
         data: {action: 'keyword'},
         type: 'post',
         async:false,
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success: function(obj) {
         alert(obj);
         }
```

Php Code

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('keyword'),array('visits','pageviews'),array('-visits'),$filter,$startDate, $endDate, $startIndex, $maxResults);

    foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
    {
        //echo $result->getKeyword()."-------------------".$result->getVisits()."<br>";
        $data[$i]['keyword']=$result->getKeyword();
        $data[$i]['visits']=$result->getVisits();
        $data[$i]['pages_visits']=round(($result->getPageviews())/$result->getVisits(),2);
        $i++;
    }echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
  url:  "Your url",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType : "json"
  success : function (response) {
  alert(response.d);
 },
 error : function (response) {
  alert(response.d);
}
})
```

And , make sure your code behind function is WBMETHOD.